# doGet method in a servlet

Tags: servlets

This is something im trying to implement. I have written the doGet method , how do i map the doPost method now ?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward="";
    String act = request.getParameter("act");
    if (act != null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") &&
           act.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
       forward= "/Login.jsp";
    } else if (act!= null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") &&
            act.equalsIgnoreCase("register")) {
        forward = LIST_USER;
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
    } else {
        forward = "/Login.jsp";
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean with "map the doPost method"? Also, please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle POST just like GET you could do

```
protected void doPost((HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to treat POST and GET in similar way then you can add a third method

```
doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
```

and call it from both

> doGet and do Post

eg

```
doSomething(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default code generated by Netbeans IDE.

Keep your code in common method and map it to your invoking method.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
} 

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
} 

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```